# Fit imageView and textView in one small layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a tiny linearlayout that I have to fit an imageView and a textView in. I know this is a terrible way to make an app. I'm just trying to test to see if this would work. The code below only shows the imageview and not the textView. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is textview or imageview's size is fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer ended up being to give the textView a weight of 0 and the imageView a weight of 1. That way, textView showed up perfectly but only took as much space as it needed, and the imageView took up the rest of the space. Perfect1

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want it to look like. If you want the LinearLayout to be split in half, then in your ImageView set

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

The views inside the LinearLayout get space in proportion to their `layout_weight` so if your ImageView has `layout_weight="0"` it will get 0 proportion of the View.

Comment: Alright, so both the imageView and the TextView have weights of 1, but the textView is still half cutoff. I see half text and entire image.

Comment: Hmmm. You could try change the TextView layout_weight to 2, then it would split 2-1. Otherwise maybe reduce the font size in the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

You should use weight like that:

android:layout_weight="2" in LinearLayout

and layout_weight="1" in imageView and textView

so that both of your view will occupy half of space

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
```